# Gesture to Trigger 3D View/ Changing Camera Perspective in MapView

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

How do we change the angle of the mapview using gesture?

Double tap to Zoom, Pinch to Zoom in and Out. But what is the gesture to change the angle to 3d?

Comment: Pan up and down with two fingers.

Comment: The only reason I didn't post it as an answer is that this question doesn't conform to the (somewhat narrow) guidelines of [topics appropriate on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'd actually suggest you delete this question. Nonetheless, glad to help.